# Window Tortoisehg, realised I cannot use Bitbucket, is there free alternative for home use (with cheap annual subscription) which is easy to setup

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

Window Tortoisehg, realized I cannot use Bitbucket, is there free alternative for home use (with a cheap annual subscription) that is easy to setup. Many answer found here are outdated since Bitbucket no longer support Tortoisehg. I'm open for suggestion. I looked into GitHub but had no luck in making push works

Answer (score 1):

1. You still *can* use Bitbucket and any other Git-hosting with hg-git extension in Mercurial (ssh and https pushes aren't a problem at all - I *have and use* Github repos from my THG)
2. You can see at pure [Mercurial hostings](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MercurialHosting), but I'll recommend starting from

- Helix TeamHub (free)
- SF.net (terrible old interface, but..)
- [Heptapod Hosting](https://about.heptapod.host/pricing.html) (paid, but not overpriced)

Comment: So what I need to do to make ButBucket with Tortoisehg?

Comment: @riscy - it will be a different question, isn't it?! Start with such pre-reqs: fresh THG (6.*), enabled hggit + bookmark (bundled) extensions, BB-account and (even new, empty) Git-repo in it

Answer (score 1):

[Heptapod](https://about.heptapod.host/) is one commercial (not free) example. They say:

> The power of GitLab Core and Mercurial combined ... Access your
> Mercurial repository through HTTPS, SSH or the Web UI.

One side-benefit of using their services is that they themselves host the repositories for numerous Mercurial tools including TortoiseHG, etc. Perhaps / presumably the commercial side helps to financially support all of that:

https://foss.heptapod.net/explore/projects/trending